# How to use nested for-loops to find the x and y of a linear equation

Tags: python, for-loop, algebra

I'm trying to find how many 10 and 50 dollar bills go into $1760 if there are only 160 bills.  I figured, with the help of a friend, that using a nested for-loop is the best way to go but I'm having issues with implementation.  My idea is to iterate every x one-by-one until 160 and if then the equation != 1760, I increment y by 1 and restart.

These are the equations:
`10x + 50y = 1760`,
`x + y = 160`

My desired output is: `10(156) + 50(4) = 1760`.  But so far, all I've been getting is this:

```
10(1) + 50(0) = 10
10(2) + 50(1) = 70
10(3) + 50(2) = 130
10(4) + 50(3) = 190
10(5) + 50(4) = 250
...
...
...
10(156) + 50(30) = 3060
10(157) + 50(30) = 3070
10(158) + 50(30) = 3080
10(159) + 50(30) = 3090
10(160) + 50(30) = 3100
```

And for some reason, y stuck at 30 starting when x = 31.  I don't know why.  Anyways, this is my code:

```
for i in range(1, 161):
    print("10" + "(" + str(i) + ") + 50" + "(" + str(y) + ")" + " = " + str((10*i)+(50*y)))
    if ((10*i)+(50*y) < 1760):
        y += 1
```

I don't want the exact answer.  I just want to know where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Once you have reached 1760, y won't be ever incremented as ((10*i)+(50*y) < 1760) will always be false.

Comment: @JónásBalázs and this happens at `y=30` explaining why y is 'stuck' there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Why your `y` gets 'stuck' at 30:*

Once the sum exceeds 1760, `y` never gets incremented again as `(10*x + 50*y) < 1760` is always `False`. This happens at `x=31` and `y=30`, which is why your `y` is 'stuck' at 30.

---

Your approach is almost complete but there is **a minor bug in the logic**:

Instead of running the 10-bills, `x`, up to 160 and increment the 50-bills, `y`, by one only if the amount exceeds the desired sum, you can run the 10-bills up to 160 and directly set the amount of 50-bills in each iteration to be `y = 160 - x`. This is because you enforce this condition (`160 = x + y`) so only configurations that fulfill this requirement need to be considered.

So, you were right in that **you only need a single `for` loop**, but you can set `y` in every iteration directly as `160 = x + y`, and then you only need to check if the amount is correct.

So the *Ansatz* for this solution looks something like:

```
for x in range(0, 161):
    y = 160 - x
    # calculate the sum
    # if the sum is correct, break
```

Comment: Thank you.  I've accepted your answer but because I'm less than 15 reps, I can't upvote you, unfortunately.  If you think that this was a well-asked question, could you give me an upvote?

Comment: @OnurOzbek I do think it is a well-asked question!

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

> My idea is to iterate every x one-by-one until 160 and if then the
>   equation != 1760, I increment y by 1 and restart.

The problem here is that you're not actually writing a nested for loop. A nested for loop is of the form:

```
for(...):
   ...
   for(...):
```

Instead, you're incrementing `y` even when you're going through the `x`s the first time, since you have that if  statement. It's getting "stuck" because `30*10+29*50 = 1750`, but once you run the loop again, `31*10+30*50 = 1810` which is greater than 1760, and so the if statement evaluates to false and `y` never increments again.  So instead, you'll want to create two for-loops nested like I demonstrated above, and after the inner one finishes, you'll want to increment `y` by 1 (which is what the for loop does automatically).

Edit from the comments:

Your code will want to look something like this:

```
for y in range(0,161):
   ...
   for x in range(0,161):
      ... #go through and check if the equations are satisfied
```

Note that the above is equivalent to:

```
x = 0
y = 0
while(y <= 160):
   ...
   while(x <= 160):
      ... #go through and check if the equations are satisfied
      x+=1 #add 1 to x
   y+=1 #when the second loop is done iterating, add 1 to y and loop again
```

If you examine what's happening here, when `y=0`, the computer is going to see the inner for loop and start running through every number for `x` between 0 and 160, and then after that point, if no match is found, the loop will run again (and since it's a for loop rather than a while loop, the incrementing of `y` by 1 already happens automatically).

Comment: You said "after the inner one finishes, you'll want to increment `y` by 1.  The inner for-loop is the 2nd one I assume.  Don't I increment `y` by 1 when the outer for-loop finishes?

Comment: And also.  What do I tell the computer after the first loop, before the 2nd inner one?

Comment: @OnurOzbek please see my edit. One tip I'd suggest is writing the nested for loop structure like I did and nothing else—just printing out the x and y values first to see what's happening. Then you can incorporate the logic.

Comment: Thank you, rb612.  If you think that this question was well asked, could you give me an upvote?

Answer (score 2):

Can't comment yet so sorry.
rb612 has rightly explained the issue.

replace your code after the second line as

```
for y in range(1, 160-i):
     if((10*i)+(50*y) <= 1760):
          y += 1
     else: break
```